# Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:mport org.baeldung.entity.QPerson cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, querydsl

I am developing the `Spring JPA QueryDSL` example. I am simply following example from link: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/querydsl, it appear me a nice tutorial. When I compiled this project, it gets compiled successfully. But when trying to execute the test case, I see following error coming.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personDaoImpl' defined in file [E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target\classes\org\baeldung\dao\PersonDaoImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.baeldung.dao.PersonDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.baeldung.entity.QPerson cannot be resolved
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a type
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a variable
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a type
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a variable
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a type
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a variable
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a type
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a variable
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a type
    QPerson cannot be resolved to a variable
```

From the error message, it's clear that QPerson classes is not finding to the code.

```
PersonDao.java
public interface PersonDao {

    public Person save(Person person);

    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameQueryDSL(String firstname);

    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameAndSurnameQueryDSL(String firstname, String surname);

    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameInDescendingOrderQueryDSL(String firstname);

    public int findMaxAge();

    public Map<String, Integer> findMaxAgeByName();
}
```

PersonDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Person save(final Person person) {
        em.persist(person);
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameQueryDSL(final String firstname) {
        final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        final QPerson person = QPerson.person;

        return query.from(person).where(person.firstname.eq(firstname)).list(person);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameAndSurnameQueryDSL(final String firstname, final String surname) {
        final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        final QPerson person = QPerson.person;

        return query.from(person).where(person.firstname.eq(firstname).and(person.surname.eq(surname))).list(person);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> findPersonsByFirstnameInDescendingOrderQueryDSL(final String firstname) {
        final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        final QPerson person = QPerson.person;

        return query.from(person).where(person.firstname.eq(firstname)).orderBy(person.surname.desc()).list(person);
    }

    @Override
    public int findMaxAge() {
        final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        final QPerson person = QPerson.person;

        return query.from(person).list(person.age.max()).get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> findMaxAgeByName() {
        final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
        final QPerson person = QPerson.person;

        return query.from(person).transform(GroupBy.groupBy(person.firstname).as(GroupBy.max(person.age)));
    }
}
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <!-- PersistenceUnit for datastore -->
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                      value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

db-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
        >

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.baeldung" />

    <import resource="test-db.xml" />
</beans>
```

test-db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" name="EntityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" name="TransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

PersonDaoTest.java

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class PersonDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    //

    @Test
    public void testCreation() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Erich", "Gamma"));
        final Person person = new Person("Kent", "Beck");
        personDao.save(person);
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameQueryDSL("Kent").get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultipleFilter() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Erich", "Gamma"));
        final Person person = personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Beck"));
        final Person person2 = personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameAndSurnameQueryDSL("Ralph", "Johnson").get(0);
        Assert.assertNotSame(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(person2.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrdering() {
        final Person person = personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma"));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));
        final Person person2 = personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameInDescendingOrderQueryDSL("Kent").get(0);
        Assert.assertNotSame(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(person2.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxAge() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma", 20));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson", 35));
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago", 30));

        final int maxAge = personDao.findMaxAge();
        Assert.assertTrue(maxAge == 35);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxAgeByName() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma", 20));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson", 35));
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago", 30));

        final Map<String, Integer> maxAge = personDao.findMaxAgeByName();
        Assert.assertTrue(maxAge.size() == 2);
        Assert.assertSame(35, maxAge.get("Ralph"));
        Assert.assertSame(30, maxAge.get("Kent"));
    }
}
```

[image]

I was able to successfully compile the code:

```
E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl>mvn clean install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building querydsl 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-apt-plugin:1.0.3:process (default) @ querydsl ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Building jar: E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target\querydsl-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ querydsl ---
[INFO] Installing E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\target\querydsl-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\prateek\.m2\repository\com\baeldung\querydsl\0.1-SNAPSHOT\querydsl-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing E:\Advance Java\Eugen\Complete\tutorials\querydsl\pom.xml to C:\Users\prateek\.m2\repository\com\baeldung\querydsl\0.1-SNAPSHOT\querydsl-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.403 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-26T12:30:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/320M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <querydsl.version>2.5.0</querydsl.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.5.10</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Persistence Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQLDB Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb-j5</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compile src folder without annotation processing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- QueryDSL plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduced this error and I also see same issue. Since you're using `Java 8`, you need to update `spring framework version to 4.x.x` (since `java 8` needs `spring 4.x`). **Also you need to use following build plugins in order to get `QPerson` class to your `DAOImpl` class. Hope this will help**.

Updated pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <querydsl.version>2.5.0</querydsl.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.5.10</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Persistence Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQLDB Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb-j5</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <!-- ======== Project Build ======== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compile src folder without annotation processing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Specifies the directory in which the query types are generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- States that the APT code generator should look for JPA annotations -->
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: which one should I add?